# Problem running a python script at boot | raspberry is not connected to a monitor - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi, startup

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero and I am using it to take pictures and measure the luminosity values from a light sensor according to a certain inclination provided by an accelerometer. I want the code to run at start-up without being connected to anything just a power font, maybe an external battery.

The script that I wrote has a loop, and inside the loop takes the values of acceleration from the sensor in the x, y and z direction and calculates the inclination (pitch and roll) using those values. Then it has an if statement that says if the roll and pitch values are within a certain range, takes a picture and saves it in a specific folder and writes the luminosity values inside a text file.

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import mpu6050library
import tsl2591library
import time
import math

filename = 1

g = 9.8065

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1600, 1200)
camera.framerate = 120
camera.rotation = -90

mpu = mpu6050library.mpu6050(0x68)

tsl = tsl2591library.Tsl2591()

while True:
    accel_data = mpu.get_accel_data()
    ax = accel_data['x']
    ay = accel_data['y']
    az = accel_data['z']
    full, ir = tsl.get_full_luminosity()
    lux = tsl.calculate_lux(full, ir)

    if (-g < ax < g):
        roll = (math.asin(ax/g))*(180/math.pi)
    else:
        roll = 90.0
        
    if az == 0:
        pitch = 90
    else:
        pitch = math.atan(ay/az)*(180/math.pi)
    
    if ((-18 < roll < 20) and (-18 < pitch < 18)):
        camera.capture("/home/pi/RPI2/pictures/" + '%s.jpg' %filename)
        file = open("/home/pi/RPI2/lum_values.txt", "a")
        file.write("%s" %filename + "  - LUX: %s" %lux + " | FULL: %s" %full + " | IR: %s" %ir + "\n")
        file.close()
        filename = filename + 1
    time.sleep(.6)
```

When I run this code from the Thonny ide, everything works as it should, pictures are saved in the folder and the luminosity values are written in the text file.
I also tried running this code at start-up, using crontab, and having my HDMI cable connected to the rasp and to a monitor, and it also works fine.

The problem begins when I try to run the code at start-up without connecting an HDMI cable and monitor, and powering the rasp with an external battery. Every time I try this, the folder, where the pictures should be, is empty and the text file is also empty. Sometimes it saves only one picture and the text file gets corrupted.
I also tried with a much simpler code, that just takes pictures from time to time and saves it in a folder and the same thing happened. If the HDMI cable is connected to the rasp, I can see the pictures being saved inside the folder, if the HDMI cable is disconnected and I power the rasp with an external battery, once I open the RPI, the folder is empty.

I am not sure, but I think that the problem may be due to the code being runned without the GUI initialized, that happens when I don't connect the HDMI cable.

Do you know what might be the problem here?? And how can I achieved what I want??

Thank you in advance,

Afonso

Comment: You could try using `sudo raspi-config` to set a default screen resolution. `2) Display Options` -> `D1 Resolution` -> `Default`.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Yes. It did worked. Thank you so much.